# getting exact sql type of query's result rowset in python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database

As far as I know, standard Python DB api does not provide exact SQL type information of result rowset.

Is there anyway to get exact SQL type and some more detailed information like tinyint, bigint, nvarchar(100) for some result rowset rather than truncated python type like int, str ... ?

I think portability or module dependency is not important - something just work would be fine. (I'm working on windows, MS-SQL.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.description` after your query to retrieve information regarding your data-types amongst other things.

```
cursor.execute('select some_column from some_table')
print cursor.description
```

> [.description](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)

```
        This read-only attribute is a sequence of 7-item
        sequences.  

        Each of these sequences contains information describing
        one result column: 

          (name, 
           type_code, 
           display_size,
           internal_size, 
           precision, 
           scale, 
           null_ok)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though 'description' member in cursor object does not provide exact SQL type information as my knowledge. (For example, there is no way to distinguish xml/nvarchar/varchar ...)